# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/u163876569/public_html/register.php on line 86

Tags: php, mysql

I have no idea what this error means dose anyone know what it means

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   /home/u163876569/public_html/register.php on line 86

```
$checkUsername = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
```

Thats line 86

Comment: Check if your PDO connection is successful first.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your DB first

```
$odb = new PDO("mysql:host=$my_db_host;dbname=$my_db_database", $my_db_username, $my_db_password);
```

if there is no error produced on this and you still get that `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object` error, i can guess maybe something is wrong with the scope of `$odb` variable

Comment: Why are you catching the exception? This is exactly the kind of thing that leads to the kind of error the OP is seeing.

Comment: @deceze whats wrong with that? im assuming 1) he is in development 2) he will see the echo

Comment: If `new PDO` throws an exception, that means it could not connect to the database. If you can't connect to the database, there's pretty much no reason to execute any of the following code; you want your application to stop in that case. By catching the exception without `exit`ing, you're actually preventing the application from stopping as it should. Just simply don't catch the exception, which causes the error message to be displayed *and* the application to stop.

Comment: @deceze yup you are correct, i ll fix that code a bit

Comment: Just. Simply. **Do. Not. Catch.** The. Exception.

Comment: @deceze wont the getMessage provide something usefull to dev?

Comment: Have you ever seen an uncaught exception?! It displays the error message and much more! http://3v4l.org/LoggW#v510 You can customise what it should and shouldn't show in development vs. production through php.ini settings and/or custom exception handlers.

Comment: @deceze i love getting corrected, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

check the object `$odb` because it is not created.
try to print `$odb`:

```
var_dump($odb); die;
```

if give you error that means your `$odb` not created yet.